# Purge Artemis ActiveMQServer queues in Java

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

I have an instance of [ActiveMQServerImpl](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/master/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/impl/ActiveMQServerImpl.java) in my integration tests and in my SetUp method I want to purge all queues in the server.  I can't seem to find any methods that can do this.  For performance reasons I'd like to avoid recreating the Artemis server bean for every single test.  Am I just missing something?

I've tried both:

```
System.out.println(testBroker.locateQueue(new SimpleString(queueName)).deleteAllReferences()); 
System.out.println(testBroker.locateQueue(new SimpleString(queueName)).getMessageCount());
```

and:

```
((QueueControl)testBroker.getManagementService().getResource(ResourceNames.QUEUE + queueName)).removeMessages(""); 
((QueueControl)testBroker.getManagementService().getResource(ResourceNames.QUEUE + queueName)).countMessages("");
```

Both show no change in message count and I continue to see messages go through to my `@JMSListener` annotated method.

Comment: Are you stopping your client(s) before you try to clear the queue? What does `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.Queue#getDeliveringCount()` return?

Comment: The same thing getMessageCount() returns.  So I guess I just need to stop the jms client before calling deleteAllReferences()?

Comment: `getMessageCount()` includes messages which are in the process of being delivered (which means they've been sent to a client but have not yet been acknowledged by the client). Messages which are being delivered are not deleted by `deleteAllReferences()` or `removeMessages()`. You should stop all your clients (e.g. drop their connections) so that the messages are cancelled back to the queue and then they can be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API call to purge *all* the queues in the broker. One way for you to do this would be to get all the queue names from the `ActiveMQServerControl`, lookup the queues, & call `deleteAllReferences()` on all of them, e.g.:

```java
for (String queueName : server.getActiveMQServerControl().getQueueNames()) {
   Queue queue = server.locateQueue(SimpleString.toSimpleString(queueName));
   if (queue != null) {
      queue.deleteAllReferences();
   }
}
```

Ensure that all your clients are stopped when this code is executed otherwise messages which are "in delivery" (i.e. messages which have been sent to a client but have not yet been acknowledged by the client) will not be deleted.

Comment: Hmm, my JmsListener is still receiving messages from the previous test.  deleteAllReferences() is returning 0 and getMessageCount() is returning > 0 after deleteAllReferences() is run.  I'll update my question with more information.

Comment: I tried calling `stop()` on my `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` before `deleteAllReferences()` but the behavior is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure how `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.stop()` correlates to the underlying JMS connection/session/consumer implementation. What does `getDeliveringCount()` say after you invoke `stop()`? What does `getConsumerCount()` say?

Comment: Yea it doesn't seem to result in the consumer being removed according to `getConsumerCount`.  Looking for another way..

Comment: How do I stop my JmsListener is such a way that the deliveringMessages either go away or are removed when i call `deleteAllReferences()`?  Everything I'm seeing online says that to stop the listener I just need to stop the JmsListenerEndpointRegistry or its listenerContainers and I've stopped both.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Spring to answer that question. As I mentioned earlier, I'm not sure how `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.stop()` correlates to the underlying JMS connection/session/consumer implementation. I recommend you ask a new question regarding this and tag it with `spring-jms` or ditch Spring and just use the JMS API. For what it's worth the JMS API is really not complex.